# Does React always works in strict mode

Tags: reactjs

> index.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import App from './App';
ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

> App.js
> import React, { Component } from 'react';

```
class App extends Component {
  render() {
    a = 10;
    console.log(a);
    return <h1>HelloWorld</h1>;
  }
}

export default App;
```

> As I am not wrapping my App component inside React.StrictMode Component then Why is it still showing 'a' is not defined error
> [link for my error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JkR7C.png)

Comment: It is not React.js specific error, This is a linting error, Create-react-app uses eslint internally. You have to declare the variable before using it.

Comment: @mpgbk Does it mean 'use strict' gets injected by the eslint internally?

Comment: No, its not about 'use strict', eslint has numerous rules, this is one of them no-undef(see in the screenshot you shared), don't confuse it with the use strict, BTW you can also switch off this rule, then you wont get this error.

Answer (score 5):

You should declare the variable:

```
let a = 10;
```

Comment: Why should I declare if I am not using strict mode in react

Comment: Its not related to the Strict Mode, but for the basics of javascript language. The StrictMode is a tool for highlighting potential problems in an application. Like Fragment, StrictMode does not render any visible UI. It activates additional checks and warnings for its descendants.

Comment: even If I don't declare It gets declared to it's enclosing scope right?That's default behaviour of javascript in non-strict mode

Comment: @Santhosh The "default" javascript is "bad" javascript. It has a lot of problems. The whole point of strict mode, ES6 etc. is to *fix* the language, e.g. avoid variable hoisting.